# Wpf - Binding Combobox Values inside GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, enums

I have a problem for WPF assoccolation 
GridViewColumn Values to Combobox Items Values

**I'm using enum objects for Fill to combobox.**

Can't binding GridItemColumn(durum) to ComboboxItems

> ENUM

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
public enum eViziteDurumlari
{
    [Description("Onaysız")]
    Onaysiz = 0,
    [Description("Onaylı")]
    Onayli = 1,
    [Description("Hepsi")]
    Hepsi = 99
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
public enum eViziteDurum
{
    [Description("Onaysız")]
    Onaysiz = 0,
    [Description("Onaylı")]
    Onayli = 1,

}
```

> ENUM CLASSES

```
   public class EnumDescriptionTypeConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public EnumDescriptionTypeConverter(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
                if (fi != null)
                {
                    var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
                    return ((attributes.Length > 0) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(attributes[0].Description))) ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}

public class EnumBindingSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private Type _enumType;
    public Type EnumType
    {
        get { return this._enumType; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._enumType)
            {
                if (null != value)
                {
                    Type enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(value) ?? value;
                    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
                        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be for an Enum.");
                }

                this._enumType = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public EnumBindingSourceExtension() { }

    public EnumBindingSourceExtension(Type enumType)
    {
        this.EnumType = enumType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (null == this._enumType)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The EnumType must be specified.");

        Type actualEnumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(this._enumType) ?? this._enumType;
        Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(actualEnumType);

        if (actualEnumType == this._enumType)
            return enumValues;

        Array tempArray = Array.CreateInstance(actualEnumType, enumValues.Length + 1);
        enumValues.CopyTo(tempArray, 1);
        return tempArray;
    }
}
```

> DATA TABLE

```
    private DataTable DataTableOlustur()
    {
        Islemler = null;
            using (Islemler = new DataTable())
            {
                Islemler.Columns.Add("firmaadi", typeof(string));
                Islemler.Columns.Add("firmakodu", typeof(string));
                Islemler.Columns.Add("tckimliknr", typeof(string));
                Islemler.Columns.Add("adisoyadi", typeof(string));
                Islemler.Columns.Add("bas_istirahat", typeof(DateTime));
                Islemler.Columns.Add("bit_istirahat", typeof(DateTime));
                Islemler.Columns.Add("durum", typeof(int));
                return Islemler;
            }

        return null;
    }
```

> XAML

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstItems">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridView" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" TextSearch.Text="True">
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Firma Kodu"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding firmakodu}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="220" Header="Firma Adı"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding firmaadi}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="TC Kimlik No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding tckimliknr}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="auto" Header="Adı Soyadı"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding adisoyadi}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="İstirahat Baş. Tarihi" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding bas_istirahat,StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="İstirahat Bit. Tarihi"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding bit_istirahat,StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Durum">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="150"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:EnumBindingSource {x:Type local:eViziteDurum}}}" 
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=durum}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>

        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I can't see DataTable Values to Combobox

I'm sorry for bad english

[image]

Comment: I don't understand... `Onayli = 2` but in your picture there is a `1` and you write it should be `Onayli`? Also I'm not quite sure what `local:EnumBindingSource` is doing.

Comment: Your 1 is Onaylı but if you looking at the index side, it was 0th try to use 0.

Comment: I change 0 = Onaysiz, 1 = Onayli, Can't change result,
Don't binding Grid Items (durum) with Combobox Items

Comment: Confirmed the problem... with an `ItemsSource` of enum value type and a SelectedValue binding to `int`, the whole thing is not working. You could try using a converter on `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=durum}"` that is explicitely converting between `int` and `eViziteDurum` values

Comment: A side note regarding your queston: when you have a problem with a `ComboBox`, you should try to use _only_ a combobox to reproduce the problem (not a combobox in a `DataGrid` with some `DataTable` behind). For your issue it was enough to set up a static 2-value enum type array as itemssource and to bind the selected value to some integer property. Everything else is just distracting from the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComboBox.ItemsSource` is filled with enum values and it will not auto-convert the `SelectedValue` between `int` and the enum type, so a converter is needed there.

Code:

```
public class EnumIntegerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // probably add some code to ensure the enum type is actually set
    // or move it to the converter parameter in order to use the same converter instance with different types
    public Type EnumType { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // probably add some sanety checks on the involved types and values
        return Enum.ToObject(EnumType, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // probably add some sanety checks on the involved types and values
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
    }
}
```

XAML resource

```
<local:EnumIntegerConverter x:Key="enumConverter" EnumType="{x:Type local:eViziteDurum}"/>
```

XAML usage

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedValue="{Binding Path=durum,Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Very Thanks for answer, grek40!